# How to let the python in cygwin use the package installed in windows?

Tags: python, cygwin

I installed python on both cygwin and windows. However, there is no package installed in cygwin's site-packages. Here the directory is `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. In contrast, they are all installed in `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages`. Since I installed the packages in `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages`, `pip` in cygwin will skip the installation of those packages. Is there a method I directly use the packages in windows?

Comment: Do not do it. Install the proper `python2-*` package from cygwin setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure (in cygwin bash) that `python2` and/or `python3` is/are ahead of the windows versions of the programs in your path. As of this writing, python 2, if installed, can be called as`python` or `python2`, while python 3 is called `python3`. This may change as more Linux distributions switch to using python 3 as the default. Use `python -V` or `python3 -V` to verify that you get the cygwin version of python when running bash. (I no long install python 2.)

```
$ which python
which: no python in (**"your path"**)
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.4
```

Then verify that you can run the appropriate version of pip for your python. To be absolutely sure of which version you are using, run

```
$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Now you should be able to install most packages from [PiPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) by replacing `pip` or `pip3` with `python -m pip` or `python3 -m pip`.

If you try to install a package that requires compilation, i.e, one that is distributed as a binary package on windows, you will need to have the `gcc` compiler tool chain, and possibly the `python-devel` or `python3-devel` package. BTW, always use the latest cygwin setup program from [cygwin.com](https://cygwin.com/index.html). You  may also need to install any required cygwin packages using setup before the package will install.

HTH

Doug